# change and delete selected items from list - PHP

Tags: php

I have built a website which has lots of lists/tables (based on php). I am trying to make a `Change All` and `Delete All` system for the lists. I have already added `checkbox` to all individual list items. I also have one checkbox to select all those items with one click. Now I am stuck at how to execute the change and delete option. It's been 3 days...

- I have done the `Change All` code right. But I can't figure out `Delete All` part.
- I don't know to pass the $targetpage variable to make it redirect after that.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>List 1</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3-theme-purple.css">
<?php include('dbcon.php');?>
<style>a {text-decoration: none;}</style>

<!--Select All-->
<script>
 function checkAll(ele) {
     var checkboxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
     if (ele.checked) {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = true;
             }
         }
     } else {
         for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
             console.log(i)
             if (checkboxes[i].type == 'checkbox') {
                 checkboxes[i].checked = false;
             }
         }
     }
 }
</script>

<body>
<!--?php include ('header.php');?-->

<form name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajaxAction.php" method="post">
<div class="w3-container">
    <div class="w3-padding-32 w3-center">
        <input class="w3-btn w3-green" type="submit" name="chkbox" value="Change All" />
        <input class="w3-btn w3-red" type="submit" value="Delete All">
    </div>
<center>
<table class="w3-table-all" style="width: auto;">
    <tr class="w3-theme">
        <th><input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" onchange="checkAll(this)" name="chk[]" /></th>
        <th>Data</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="w3-check" type="checkbox" name="chkbox[]" />
        </td>
        <td class="w3-small" >
            The data is displayed here.
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>
</form>
<br>
<!--?php include ('footer.php');?-->
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the ajaxAction.php code:

```
<!--Change-->
    <?php
    if ($_REQUEST['chkbox']) {
        $targetpage = $_REQUEST['targetpage'];
        $change = array ();
        $change = $_REQUEST['chkbox'];
        for($c=0;$c<count($change); $c++){

            $sql_all = "update `table` set `value`='123' WHERE `id` = '$change[$c]'";
            mysql_query($sql_all) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    ?>
    <script>
        var targetpage = "<?php echo $targetpage ?>";
        location.href=targetpage+"?done";
    </script>
    <?php } ?>

    <!--Delete-->
    <?php ?>
    <script>
        var targetpage = "<?php echo $targetpage ?>";
        location.href=targetpage+"?done";
    </script>
```

**With my current code, I am only able to use the selected array `chkbox[]` for one processing i.e. `Change All`. I don't know how to use the same array for `Delete All` button.**

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Instead of sending javscript to the browser and doing a complete round trip why not use PHP's `header('Location: another_page.php');`

Comment: Am I right in assuming you would like someone to write the `Delete All` processing for you?

Comment: SO is **not a free Coding or Code Conversion or Debugging or Tutorial or Library Finding service**
You also have to show that you have made some effort to solve your own problem.

Comment: @RiggsFolly ok, I'll use php. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Just tell me how can i use the same array `chkbox[]` for both the `Change All` & `Delete All`buttons. If you look at the ajaxAction code, I have used `chkbox` for Change. Now I can't use it for Delete function OR IN OTHER WORDS how will the query know which button sent the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the trial and error method and trying for two weeks, I finally got the solution ON MY OWN and I have a serious gripe because no one from this forum cared to show me the solution.

It was simple. All I had to do was to use `$_POST` instead of `$_REQUEST` and use different names both the buttons like this:

```
<input class="w3-btn w3-green" type="submit" name="submit1" value="Change All">
<input class="w3-btn w3-red" type="submit" name="submit2" value="Delete All">
```

So, I changed `ajaxAction.php` to:

```
<?php
//Change All
if(isset($_POST['submit1'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['chkbox'])){
        $targetpage = $_REQUEST['targetpage'];
        foreach($_POST['chkbox'] as $selected){
            $sql_all = "update `table` set value='123' WHERE `id` = '$selected'";
            mysql_query($sql_all) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>

<script>
    location.href="tables.php?done";
</script>
<?php } ?>


<?php
//Delete All
if(isset($_POST['submit2'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['chkbox'])){
        foreach($_POST['chkbox'] as $selected){

            $sql_all = "DELETE FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '$selected'";
            mysql_query($sql_all) or die(mysql_error());
        }
    }
?>

<script>
    location.href="tables.php?done";
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

All you had to do was tell me that I should use `$_POST`. No one from Stack Overflow helped me.